# how to run a command in tasks.loop discord.py bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

so im trying to get a command to run every 5 minutes on my dsicrod.py bot and need ctx to get guild members and certain details like that so I need it in a bot.command, but I cant have that properly do that without tasks.loop(minutes=5) so I tried getting it to send the command with tasks.loop but it wouldn't work so I went to the pythin discord and got help they got me to this point

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def update_member_count(ctx): 
    await ctx.send(ctx.guild.member_count)
    channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, id=829355122122424330)
    await channel.edit(name = f'Member Count: {ctx.guild.member_count}')


@tasks.loop(minutes=5)
async def update_member_count2(ctx):
    await update_member_count(ctx)
```

and It still gives errors saying that ctx arg is missing in update_member_count2. pls help

Comment: How are you starting the task?

Comment: its starting in the bot.event on ready

Comment: @BurnDownTheWorld Did you take a look at my answer? There was/is no comment from your side to that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your `loop`-function in another way. Your approach is a bit unclear to me.

**Try out the following:**

```py
async def update_member_count(ctx):
    while True:
        await ctx.send(ctx.guild.member_count)
        channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, id=YourID)
        await channel.edit(name=f'Member Count: {ctx.guild.member_count}')
        await asyncio.sleep(TimeInSeconds)


@bot.command()
async def updatem(ctx):
    bot.loop.create_task(update_member_count(ctx))  # Create loop/task
    await ctx.send("Loop started, changed member count.") # Optional
```

*(Or you simply create the task in your `on_ready` event, depends on you)*

**What did we do?**

- Created a loop out of a function (`async def update_member_count(ctx):`)
- Exectued `updatem` one time to activate the loop
- Changed your actual command to a "function"

Comment: im not sure if its working, its not sending anything so ill need to see if there's anything I did wrong that might have messed with that

Comment: Works fine for me, which version did you try out? If you just copy the code you should be fine. Also pay attention to the correct indentation.

Comment: I copyed and pasted but its not outputing it

Answer (score 1):

You could go with @Dominik's answer but its near impossible to stop a running While loop. Going ahead with discord.py tasks.
If you want to start the task with a command:

```py
async def start(ctx):
    update_member_count2.start(ctx)
```

If you want to start it when the bot starts, you have to slightly modify the code

```py
@tasks.loop(minutes=5)
async def update_members():
    guild = bot.get_guild(guildID)
    channel = guild.get_channel(channelID)
    #update channel, don't sleep
```

```
# inside init or on_ready
if not update_members.is_running():
     update_members.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in a on_member_join event

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
  channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.channels, id=962732335386746910)
  await channel.edit(name = f'⚫┃・Members: {member.guild.member_count}')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Add the line

```
intents.message_content=True
```

This solved the issue for me

Comment: You should use the ` to format your text as code sample, it is more readable